# Alertview displayed later after the Core Data query is done?

Tags: ios, core-data, uialertview

I want to show alertview prior to querying the core data.

My core data will query hundred thousands record and it will take some time, but when I try to show the alertview, the alertview is displayed after the core data process is done?

What's wrong with it? How can I show the alertview before querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by:

```
dispatch_queue_t request_queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.appname.method", NULL);
dispatch_async(request_queue, ^{
Your long process here..
});
```

When need to update the GUI, use this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch your code to fetch data in a thread and then show the alert box.

Steps :

1. Start the thread to fetch data from DB.
2. Show the alert dialog with progress or what ever you want.
3. When the data fetch call back comes, dismiss the alert dialog.

Comment: i've tried this to use dispatch_queue_t, however it results some bugs where i didn't find if I didn't use thread